# Using Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: java, eclipse, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to get around using the Stanford CoreNLP. I used some code from the web to understand what is going on with the coreference tool. I tried running the project in Eclipse but keep encountering an out of memory exception. I tried increasing the heap size but there isnt any difference. Any ideas on why this keeps happening? Is this a code specific problem? Any directions of using CoreNLP would be awesome.

EDIT - Code Added

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;


import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;


public class testmain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "Viki is a smart boy. He knows a lot of things.";
        Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, parse, dcoref");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        pipeline.annotate(document);


        Map<Integer, CorefChain> graph = document.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.class);



        Iterator<Integer> itr = graph.keySet().iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {

             String key = itr.next().toString();

             String value = graph.get(key).toString();

             System.out.println(key + " " + value);      
        }

   }
}
```

Comment: I use corenlp in eclipse with -Xms4g and it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found similar problem when building small application using Stanford CoreNLP in Eclipse.
Increasing Eclipse's heap size will not solve your problem.
After doing search, it is **ant build tool** heap size that should be increased, but I have no idea how to do that.
So I give up Eclipse and use Netbeans instead.

**PS:** You will eventually get out of memory exception with default setting in Netbeans. But it can easily solved by adjust setting **-Xms** per application basis.

Comment: Thank you! Thats a life saver! This memory issue was driving me nuts! How did you figure out that the problem was with ant?

Comment: I did some googling. Let me know if you find way to set ant heap size.

Comment: [This] (http://soenkerohde.com/2008/06/change-eclipse-ant-settings-when-you-run-out-of-memory/) website has an answer but I'm not sure why it still isn't working. Also, if you are online, I'd like to have a chat with you!

Comment: I couldn't in this moment. I'm gonna out. You could send me an email me [kyu dot helf at gmail dot com]

Comment: Is changing to Netbeans the only way to avoid the outofmemory exception?

Comment: As far as solutions go, switching the IDE is probably the worst. You can easily set the heap size on a per-configuration basis. Open the run/debug configurations and select the "Arguments" tab. http://img.viralpatel.net/2009/10/tomcat-jvm-config.png

Answer (score 3):

Fix for eclipse: You can configure this in eclipse preference as follows

1. Windows -> Preferences ( on mac it's: eclipse ->preferences)
2. Java -> Installed JREs
3. Select the JRE and click on Edit
4. On the default VM arguments field, type in "-Xmx1024M". (or your memory preference, for 1GB of ram its 1024)
5. Click on finish or OK.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can define the heap size in right-click->run->run-configurations under the VM arguments. i have tested it on mac and it works.