# Stanford CoreNLP - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, eclipse-neon

I am trying to run simple program available on this website   https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html
**My Program**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.BufferedWriter;  
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileReader;  
import java.io.FileWriter;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.Properties;  

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation;  
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation;  
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation;  
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation;  
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation;  
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;  
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;  
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;  
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;  

public class StanfordClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Properties props = new Properties();
      props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse");

        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

        String text = "What is the Weather in Mumbai right now?";
         Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
          pipeline.annotate(document);

        List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

       for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
          // traversing the words in the current sentence
          // a CoreLabel is a CoreMap with additional token-specific methods
          for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
            // this is the text of the token
            String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
            // this is the POS tag of the token
            String pos = token.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
            // this is the NER label of the token
            String ne = token.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);

            System.out.println(String.format("Print: word: [%s] pos: [%s] ne: [%s]",word, pos, ne));
          }
        }
    }
}
```

But getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

**What I tried**
1. if I remove ner (named entity recognizer) property from above code i.e.   **props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse");**
then the code runs fine.
2.but I required ner(named entity recognizer) hence I increase heap size in eclipse.ini file up to 1g and sure that this much size is far enough for this program and also sure that heap size is not the problem in this case. I think something is missing but not getting that.

Comment: did you check the methods which are taking more memory?

Comment: how should I check?

Comment: this applicable to up to Java 5 but I am using java 8 and heap size up to 1gb is too much for this simple program

Comment: Oh I am sorry, i forgot use this http://www.khelekore.org/jmp/tijmp/

Comment: I have used eclipse memory analyzer and there is no problem related to memory

Answer (score 1):

After lots of searches gets answer here 
[Using Stanford CoreNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967544/using-stanford-corenlp)

**Use following answer:-**
 1.Windows -> Preferences
2.Java -> Installed JREs
3.Select the JRE and click on Edit
4.On the default VM arguments field, type in "-Xmx1024M". (or your memory preference, for 1GB of ram it is 1024)
5.Click on finish or OK.

Comment: I had to set the heap space to 4 GB before it worked. i.e. "-Xmx4096M" But then, it did! :) Watching Eclipse in Task Manager (Windows 10), the memory footprint went up to 5.9 GB just before the demo program finished. No surprise, Natural Language Processing requires a lot of RAM.